# Iterating over a list using ggarrange

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have the following bit of code and don't understand why the for loop isn't working. I'm new to this, so excuse me if this is obvious, but it's not actually producing a combined set of graphs (as the more brute force method does below), it just prints out each graph individually

```
library(ggpubr)
graphs <- lapply(names(hemi_split), function(i){ 
  ggplot(data=hemi_split[[i]], aes(x=type, y=shoot.mass))+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(.~host, scales="free")+ 
    theme_minimal()+
    labs(title=i)
         });graphs

for (i in 1:length(graphs)) {
  ggarrange(graphs[[i]])
} ##not working 

## this works, and is the desired output
ggarrange(graphs[[1]], graphs[[2]], graphs[[3]],
          graphs[[4]], graphs[[5]], graphs[[6]],
          graphs[[7]], graphs[[8]], graphs[[9]],
          graphs[[10]], graphs[[11]])
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `do.call` to provide all of the list elements of `graphs` as arguments of `ggarrange`:

```
library(ggpubr)
graphs <- lapply(names(mtcars)[2:5],function(x){
                ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(x = x, y = "mpg")) +
                   geom_point()})
do.call(ggarrange,graphs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

another solution using `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
ggraphs <- map(names(mtcars)[2:5],
            ~ ggplot(mtcars,aes_string(x = .x, y = "mpg")) +
              geom_point())

ggarrange(plotlist = ggraphs)
```

Comment: Hi! Does the `ncol` parameter of `ggarrenge` work this way? I used a combination of `nest`and `map2` to get my plots. And it does work, however if I try to use `ncol`, it breaks...